# Marshal and Unmarshal from JSon

Tags: json, scala, akka-http

I'm new to scala and trying to write a simple restapi.
I've got the port binding and everything is fine but i would like to cast the arrived Json to an object.
So i find these in the documentation:
http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.10/scala/http/common/marshalling.html#http-marshalling-scala
http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.10/scala/http/common/unmarshalling.html#http-unmarshalling-scala

The concept is to receive PUT request with a complex json like:

```
{
    "appId": "789456123",
    "date": "1920.06.28",
    "details": [{
        "value": "179876456"
    }, {
        "value": "10321324564"
    }, {
        "value": "123123456"
    }]
}
```

And the route.

```
protected val route =
path("feed") {
  put {
    entity(as[Data]) { data =>
      complete {
        logger.info("Arrived item [$data]")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And that's where i stucked. I dont find any good example that works without using spray. I would like to use simple marshallers and unmarshallers but i cannot find the way :(
Any idea is welcomed!

Comment: https://github.com/theiterators/akka-http-microservice

Comment: Thanks for the Tipp! It use DefaultJsonProtocol and it is missing from the 2.4.10 that we use :(

Comment: Yeah. my bad they just moved it to akka.http.scaladsl.marshallers.sprayjson. package.

Comment: Hey, here you can have the latest docu from Akka-http about marshallers and unmarshallers: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/scala/http/common/marshalling.html
http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/scala/http/common/unmarshalling.html